# How to stop Parcel from caching?

Tags: reactjs, parcel

I am using Parcel for React. Parcel is caching everytime so my changes are not getting updated most of the time. Browser is still using the old code even though it is not present there. Is there any way to stop parcel from caching?

I tried using --no-cache with parcel and its not working.